# comparing two strings, one string has a wildcard

Tags: php

I have two strings which I would like to compare.

`string1 = www.domain.com`

`string2 = *.domain.com`

Normally, if we use `if ($string1 == $string2)..` these shouldn't match as they are not equal, however, since string2 is a wildcard, I would like it to be a match.

Condition(s)

1. `*.domain.com` should match with `***anything**.domain.com*`
2. `*.domain.com` should be a mismatch for `*domain.com*` or `*something.adifferent.com*`
3. need a solution to support all TLD's i.e. `.com, .net, .org. .com.au` etc..

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you could convert first string to a regex, replacing `*` with `.*`, and escaping dots. then use that regex to see if the other string matches.

Comment: thx but not sure what you mean.. can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about 2 point that you tell in your question, but i think you need do like this:-

```
<?php


$string1 = '*.domain.com';

$string2 = 'www.domains.com';

$pattern = 'domain'; // put any pattern that you want to macth in both the string.

    if(preg_match("~\b$pattern\b~",$string1) && preg_match("~\b$pattern\b~",$string2) && substr_count($string1,'.') == substr_count($string2,'.')){
        echo 'matched';
    }else{
        echo 'not matched';
    }

?>
```

Output:-  http://prntscr.com/7alzr0

and if `string2` converted to `www.domain.com` then

http://prntscr.com/7am03m

Note:- 1. if you want the below will match also then go for the given condition.

```
example:--
$string1 = '*.domain.com'; 
$string2 = 'abc.login.domain.com'; 

if(preg_match("~\b$pattern\b~",$string1) && preg_match("~\b$pattern\b~",$string2) && substr_count($string1,'.') <= substr_count($string2,'.')){
```

Comment: I think the `$pattern` is meant to be "domain.com"

Comment: you have www.domains.com for string2.

Comment: thanks a lot to help you.thanks:))))) i voted yp already your question.it's a good one

Comment: dots have a special meaning in a regex. if you use domain.com as pattern that dot will match any character.